# How to fix Rails creating blog bundler load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i try execute command

```
rails new blog
```

i take an error like this

```
    run  bundle install
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle (LoadError)
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

when i check the 'usr/share/rubygems-integration/all' i saw there is no gem 
directory so what must i do for fix that?
ruby -v ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
rails -v Rails 5.1.4
gem -v 2.6.13

i use rvm for install ruby on rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using RVM, you should first create a gemset for your blog project:

```
rvm use 2.3.1p112@blog --create
```

Then install bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure bundler gem is install

`gem install bundler`

2) Execute

`bundle exec spring binstub --all`